# Linux video player w/ resume support

Tags: linux, video-player

I need a video player for Linux.

Requirements:

- remember playing position of playlist and video on restart
- MP4 video support

Optionally:

- .deb package

Comment: According to [TecMint](https://www.tecmint.com/10-best-open-source-video-players-for-linux-in-2015/), there's [Bomi](https://bomi-player.github.io/) which should fit that, including a PPA for Ubuntu (i.e. a `.deb` package). Not having tried it myself I'm hesistant to make that an answer, so could you take a look first?

Comment: Not sure on playlist, but on individual files VLC prompts me to resume where i was

Comment: @ivanivan vlc not support playlist resume

Comment: @Izzy deb file and project too old deb:2015-05-20 src:Aug 13, 2016 and I can't compile on debian

Comment: Ouch. Sorry to hear that. There's a [VLC addon](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154008/) promising the same, but that seems even more outdated (2014). But according to [this thread on UbuntuForums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276218), Kodi (formerly XMBC) should be capable of that – and Kodi is still well maintained AFAIK.

Comment: @Izzy I can't find resume option on kodi. found 1-2 broken link for plugin but nothing

Comment: Sorry to read that; I'm out of ideas then.